# Formula for the volume of a rectangular cube knowing the surfaces of its faces

Tags: geometry, contest-math

The surfaces of different sides of a rectangular cube are resp. $V,W$ and $U$. The volume of this rectangular cube is then:

**A)**$\qquad$$V\cdot W\cdot U$

**B)**$\qquad$$\frac{V\cdot \sqrt W + W\cdot \sqrt U + U\sqrt V }{3}$

**C)**$\qquad$$\sqrt {V\cdot W\cdot U}$

**D)**$\qquad$$\sqrt[3]{V\cdot W\cdot U}$

**E)**$\qquad$ None of the previous options.

Why is the answer A the correct one? I don't understand how multiplying 3 surfaces with let's say $2 \ \mathrm m^2,3\ \mathrm m^2$ and $4\ \mathrm m^2$. This would give a unit of $\mathrm m^6$ not $\mathrm m^3$. I probably shouldn't think in units. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You are right, answer $A$ is dimensionally wrong and cannot be the correct one.

Comment: Your reasoning with units is very good and shows that A cannot be correct.

Comment: O, then the answer should be C.

Comment: I reckon C is correct. The one who made this question was wrong or maybe there was an error.

Comment: Dimensional analysis can rule out A and D. You have to rule out B and E too.

Comment: The answer has to be $C$. If side lengths of the cube are $a, b, c$ then $ab = U, bc = V, ca = W \implies a^2b^2c^2 = UVW$. So the volume is $abc = \sqrt{UVW}$

Comment: The correct term is not "rectangular cube" but "rectangular parallelepiped" ; one encounters more and more the term "cuboid"

Comment: I have changed your former title "rectangular cube" into a title connected with the content of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cube has equal areas for all surfaces. A rectangular solid is slightly different but the cube is simpler for demonstration.

Let a cube volume  be
$\space V=2\times2\times2=8.\quad$
Each surface area is
$\space A=2\times2=4.\quad$
If we multiply these surfaces we get
$V???=\space4\times4\times4=64.\quad$
The square root of that is
$\space V=\sqrt{64}=8.\quad$
Take the example of the rectangular solid with sides of $\space 1,2,3.\quad$
The volume is $\space V=1\times2\times3=6.\quad$ If we do it the other way we have
$\space A_1=2,\space A_2=3,\space A_3=6,\space$
and $\space\sqrt{2\cdot3\cdot6}=\sqrt{36}=6.$

It is always true that
$V=\sqrt{A_1\cdot A_2\cdot A_3}\space$ so the correct answer is $\space C.\space$

Comment: Examining the dimensions of the continents OK SkyQ when

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of volume shoul be 3. So of all five options given only the third  one C is correct.